# Shortcodes showing in excerpt despite using strip_shortcodes

Tags: php, shortcode, excerpt

On my website, shortcodes are showing in the excerpts, despite the fact that WordPress should remove them automatically, and that I tried this two different solutions:

```
function remove_shortcode_from_excerpt($content) {
    $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'remove_shortcode_from_excerpt');
```

And

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

That I added in the functions.php file of my child theme.

What are my next options?

Comment: More info needed :) Are you sure that your theme is definitely using `the_excerpt ()` to display the excerpt? And if so, are you sure your `remove_shortcode_from_excerpt` is actually running? (Replace the content with `"testing"` or something to check.) As you said, WordPress does remove the shortcodes from excerpts, so there's more to this problem than meets the eye.

Comment: After a bit of digging into the theme, turns out you were right, it's not using "the_excerpt()" so my attempts definitly couldn't succeed... I'll answer my own question explaining the steps I took, if someone has the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

So, as iguanarama pointed out, the first step is to make sure that the theme you are using uses `the_excerpt()` to show the excerpt.

You'll want to go check in your `archive.php` file how it is displayed. In my theme it was using the file `'template-parts/content-front-c.php'`. Then go to this file and see what is the function displaying the excerpt. Right after the function gets the content, add `$content=strip_shortcodes($content);`, and, in my case, it worked !